# How do I sort the elements of an HashMap according to their values?

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, hashmap

I have the following `HashMap`:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

What is the simplest way to order it according to the values?

Comment: You cannot sort a HashMap, you can use a TreeMap but keys and values must be the other way around for your requirement.

Comment: Please ignore the recommendation in my previous comment. The problem with that is that there will be always a chance that multiple entries with same count, and the map doesn't allow duplicate keys. I think the best is to follow the answers with the suggestions in on sorting the list of entries.

Comment: If you are not restricted to using a `HashMap`, why not create a class which contains your word as a `String`, your count as an `int`, and and have it implement Comparable to find a max value, then just insert all of these objects into a maximum heap, and find the root node of the heap?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't sort a `Map` by the values, especially not a `HashMap`, which can't be sorted at all.

Instead, you can sort the entries:

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entries = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(map.entrySet());
Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
  public int compare(
      Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry2) {
    return entry1.getValue().compareTo(entry2.getValue());
  }
});
```

will sort the entries in ascending order of count.

Answer (score 4):

You can get a set of entries ([`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of [`Map.Entry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html)) from a map, by using [`map.entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet%28%29). Just iterate over them, and check the values by [`getValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getValue%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

A work around, if you want to them print them in order(Not storing).

1. Create a new Map (`tempMap`) and put your value as key and key as value. To make the keys unique, please add some unique value in each of the keys e.g. key1 = value1+@0.
2. Get the list of values as `map.values()` as list `myVlues`
3. Sort the `myVlues` list as `Collections.sort(myVlues)`
4. Now iterate the `myVlues`, get the corresponding `key` from `tempMap`, restore the key e.g. key.substring(0, key.length-2) and print the key and value pair.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) can keep its entries in an order defined by a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

1. We can create a comparator that will order the Map by putting the greatest value first.
2. Then, we will build a TreeMap that uses that Comparator.
3. We will then put all the entries in our `counts` map into the Comparator.
4. Finally, we will [get the first key](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#firstKey%28%29) in the map, which should be the most common word (or at least one of them, if multiple words have equal counts).

   ```
   public class Testing {
       public static void main(String[] args) {

           HashMap<String,Double> counts = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

           // Sample word counts
           counts.put("the", 100);
           counts.put("pineapple",5);
           counts.put("a", 50);

           // Step 1: Create a Comparator that order by value with greatest value first
           MostCommonValueFirst mostCommonValueFirst =  new MostCommonValueFirst(counts);

           // Step 2: Build a TreeMap that uses that Comparator
           TreeMap<String,Double> sortedMap = new TreeMap<String,Integer (mostCommonValueFirst);

           // Step 3: Populate TreeMap with values from the counts map
           sortedMap.putAll(counts);

           // Step 4: The first key in the map is the most commonly used word
           System.out.println("Most common word: " + sortedMap.firstKey());
       }
   }

   private class MostCommonValueFirst implements Comparator<String> {
      Map<String, Integer> base;

      public MostCommonValueFirst(Map<String, Integer> base) {
         this.base = base;
      }

      // Note: this comparator imposes orderings that are inconsistent with equals.    
      public int compare(String a, String b) {
         if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b)) {
             return 1;
         } else {
            return -1;
         } // returning 0 would merge keys
      }
    }
   ```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1283722/284685

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good idea. The key's comparator order can change with the values of the map. It's essentially a mutable key (as far as `TreeMap` is concerned).

Comment: Agreed, but we can still do it after we are done populating the map.